# Activity Restarts when Orientation changes android?

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation, device-orientation

I have a application ,where I am using Landscape and potrait mode. I have used **android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"** in my every activity. So When I run this on device 2.3 its completely working fine and the activity is not restarted. But  When I open the same application in android 4.0 and above the activity gets restarted whenever a orientation is changed.
 Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iconnect.collaborator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" />
    <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" />
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />


   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/cnlogomini"
        android:label="CollaborateNow"
        android:largeHeap="true"
      android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="jim.h.common.android.zxinglib.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".Register"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ppllogincopy"

           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>

<activity android:name=".Password"

           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Camerascan"

           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".TabGroup1Activity"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".newtab"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".SubmitData"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".peoplelist"

         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".GenerateQrcode"

        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".contact"

           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".peoplelistlogin"

          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".Startnew"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

            ></activity>
          <activity android:name=".projectdetails"

           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
           <activity android:name=".Signup"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
          <activity android:name=".RegisterScan"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
          <activity android:name=".peoplelistscan"

           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Profile"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".List"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Logout"

           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".scanRegister"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".scanList"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name="scanCamera"

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.iconnect.collaborator.Camera"

         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
       <activity android:name=".collaborations"

           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.iconnect.collaborator.MainActivity"


            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: do you want to block orientation change or not??

Comment: Answered several times. You should save your state and restore it.

Comment: No, I want both potrait and landscape, but the activity is getting restarted as orientation changes in 4.0 and above, but does not get restarted on 2.3.

Answer (score 12):

if your `android:targetSdkVersion="12"` or less

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

if your `android:targetSdkVersion="13"` or more

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Quote from developer.android

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
> also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
> declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
> must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
> value. That is, you must decalare
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your
> application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
> handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
> does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
> higher device).

From here: [Handling Orientation Change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add screenSize too.

"The current available screen size has changed. This represents a change in the currently available size, relative to the current aspect ratio, so will change when the user switches between landscape and portrait. However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).
Added in API level 13."